# Forward declaration of a function in Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I would like to forward-declare a function in ClojureScript. Kind of

```
(defn a [] (b))
...
(defn b [] ...)
```

I think what kind of works is to place a `(def b nil)` in front of the usage `(b)` but I wonder if there is a "better" way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `declare` does the trick. I only found documentation on it for Clojure but it seems to work in ClojureScript as well.

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/declare